# How do I merge specific rows into a new column?

Tags: r

My current dataset has an education variable which has 18 categories ranging from 'no qualifications' to 'Postgraduate'

I want to create a new education variable that will consists of only 5 categories (e.g no qualifications- primary school - secondary school - bachelors - postgrad). I would like to merge some of the 18 categories together to form one category in my new variable (e.g categories 3,4,5 into  secondary school).

Comment: See https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_collapse.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just recode the categories with `recode()` from dplyr. It goes like:

```
library(dplyr)
name_of_dataset[[number_of_old_column]] %>% recode('1st grade' = 'primary school', '2nd grade' = 'primary school')
```

and so on. Old name goes first, new name goes second. You can put the new data in a new column with `mutate()` from dplyr. It goes like:

```
name_of_dataset %>% mutate(name_of_new_column = recode(.[[number_of_old_column]], '1st grade' = 'primary school', '2nd grade' = 'primary school'))
```

Comment: Error: unexpected '=' in "bes%>%mutate(Educationlevel = recode(.[[education]], 12 ="

Comment: @Kuddiking Just after recode, you have written `.[[education]]` but it should be the ***number*** of the old column, not it's name. If you'd like to use the name, you could write `.$education` (mind the dot). So it's either `.[[3]]` or `.$education` but not `.[[education]]`.

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `EducationLevel`.
x recursive indexing failed at level 2

i Input `EducationLevel` is `recode(...)`

Comment: Can you post the exact command you've input? Also, what's the format of your dataset? Is it a data.frame, a list? Try `class(name_of_dataset)` if you don't know. Are there any NA in the EducationLevel? Try `any(is.na(name_of_dataset$EducationLevel))` if you don't know.

Comment: It is a data.frame,

Comment: > class(bes)
[1] "data.frame"
> any(is.na(bes$education))
[1] FALSE

Comment: I asked another question, could you check it out maybe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66722081/error-in-subset2x-i-exact-exact-recursive-indexing-failed-at-level-2

Comment: I've answered the other question. If could tell you where's the mistake in the `mutate()` variant, but show me the exact command you've used.